# my question is on how to calculate battery capacity

Tags: 12v

I got this from a search google, this example was given but didn't understand they got to the answer, here is the example let say you run a 250watts, 110vollts light bulb from an inverter for 5 hours.Amp-hour( 12volts) = watts-hours/12volts = 1470/12 = 122.5Ah.So i didn't get were this (1470) came from for i was expecting to see but 250 watts * 5hours which would have given me this 1250/12 = 104.16Ah.

Then this second question, How long does it take to charge a 12 volts battery with a solar panel? This is what i got from a search on google, to find the charging rate , divide the wattage of the panel by the voltage of the battery. (Amp = watts divide volts) which is 245watts/12volts which is equal 20.42Amp. So the equation now leads 140.875Amp-hours divide by 20.45A which equals about 6.9hours.I'm just lost from were they say the equation leads to 140.875 Amp-hours. Thanks.

Comment: Power \$ P = VI = V^{2}/R = I^{2}R \$

Comment: 5Ah*12=60Wh  thus T= 60Wh/250W=0.24h discharge time.... "they" were an unreliable source"  and if panel supplies 254W, charge time ideally = 60Wh/254W=0.236h  but practically twice that with lead acid battery efficiency

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your expectations is they assume the battery and solar panel put out constant voltage and current, and that *all* this energy is transferred to the load with 100% efficiency.

If the inverter was 85% efficient then to run a 250W light bulb it would need to draw 294W from the battery. 294W * 5 hours = 1470 Watt hours.

A lead-acid battery's voltage drops as it discharges, and its capacity reduces at high current draw. So a battery rated for 100Ah might only deliver 90Ah at the 5 hour rate, with voltage dropping from 12.5V to 10.5V through that time.

20.42A * 6.9 hours = 140.9Ah. However a solar panel rated for 245W at 12V will only deliver that power in full sunlight (1000W/m<sup>2</sup>). In most locations that will not be achievable, and certainly not for 6.9 hours in a single day. The solar charge controller will also have some loss which must subtracted from the total, and the battery's charging voltage is higher (up to 14.4V) so more energy is required to charge it than it will deliver on discharge.

Lead acid batteries don't like being fully discharged or charged at a high rate. The obvious solution is to oversize the battery so it has more capacity than is required. Similarly, a larger solar panel will be needed to produce sufficient power on dull days and during winter when the sun is weaker.

Comment: Thanks alot for those answers to my questions.Mr. Bruce Abbott.